# Could a modified quicksort be O(n) best case?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, big-o, quicksort

It's generally agreed that the best case for quicksort is O(nlogn), given that the array is partitioned by roughly half each time. It's also said that the worst case is order n^2, assuming that the array is sorted.

Can't we modify quicksort by setting a boolean called swap? For example,  if there is no initial swap in position for the first pass, then we can assume that the array is already sorted, therefore do not partition the data any further.

I know that the modified bubble sort uses this by checking for swaps, allowing the best case to be O(n) rather than O(n^2). Can this method be applied to quicksort? Why or why not?

Comment: You could try asking this at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com, too

Comment: You can make _any_ sorting method O(n) in best case by checking if the array is already sorted at the start. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: 9000: no, cstheory is for much more advanced questions

Comment: Does sound awfully theoretical considering that much better sorts are out there with better worst case performance and O(n) best case.

Comment: @9000: more specifically, cstheory is for research level stuff. This is undergraduate / homework level.

Comment: You can make any sorting algorithm O(n) best case by checking to see if the array is already sorted before doing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one mistake with your approach... 
For example we have an array like this:
1243 5 678

our Pivot Element is 5. After a first pass there would be no swap(because 4 and 3 are both smaller), but the array is NOT sorted. So you have to start dividing it and that leads to n log n.

Comment: Makes sense. Since we're only checking if the left is smaller than the pivot element, it doesn't always mean everything is in order. So would I be correct to assume that, for quick sort, the best case is O(nlogn) regardless of modification?

Comment: Yes there is a mathematical proof somewhere, that the best case in a sorting algorithm has to be nlogn.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work for quicksort.  In bubble sort if you do a pass through the array without making any swaps you know that the entire array is sorted.  This is because each element is compared to its neighbor in bubble sort, so you can infer that the entire array is sorted after any pass where no swaps are done.

That isn't the case in quicksort.  In quicksort each element is compared to a single pivot element.  If you go through an entire pass without moving anything in quicksort it only tells you that the elements are sorted with respect to the pivot (values less than the pivot are to its left, values greater than the pivot are to its right), not to each other.

Comment: some modified versions do pass through the array completely (no pivot) and check if it's sorted already, but of course the classic quick sort can't

Comment: @bestsss That's a separate check though.  I think the OP means to use the normal initial scan for a quicksort to check for sortedness.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is also the problem that you also get O(n) behaviour with *almost sorted* arrays in addition to the *fully sorted* input.

You can try harder to make your approach work but I don't think you can make it breach the O(n log n) boundary. There is a proof that comparison-based sorts cannot be more efficient then O(n log n) in the worst case.